# TRANSACT SQL Generate multiple rows from DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datediff

I have the following table

```
table event(
   start_tstamp [datetime],
   stop_tstamp [datetime],
   exe_name [nvarchar](50),
   machine_name [nvarchar](30)
)
```

I'd need to generate a scalar table from this table that contains one line of information for every hour difference between *start_tstamp* and *stop_tstamp* of the following form:

```
table event_temp(
   day_occured [datetime],
   hour_occured [tinyint],
   exe_name [nvarchar](50),
   machine_name [nvarchar](30)
)
```

for example table **event** contains two lines

```
"2012/12/10 07:00", "2012/12/10 09:00", "notepad.exe", "testmachine"
"2012/12/11 15:00", "2012/12/11 18:00", "notepad.exe", "foomachine"
```

The resulting **event_temp** should be the following

```
"2012/12/10 00:00", 7, "notepad.exe", "testmachine"
"2012/12/10 00:00", 8, "notepad.exe", "testmachine"
"2012/12/10 00:00", 9, "notepad.exe", "testmachine"
"2012/12/11 00:00", 15, "notepad.exe", "foomachine"
"2012/12/11 00:00", 16, "notepad.exe", "foomachine"
"2012/12/11 00:00", 17, "notepad.exe", "foomachine"
"2012/12/11 00:00", 18, "notepad.exe", "foomachine"
```

I then need to join the **event_temp** table with an existing calendar table that returns a list of dates that match those in **event_temp**

```
table calendar(
   day_occured [datetime],
   hour_occured [tinyint],
)
```

That would just contain:

```
"2012/12/10 00:00", 0
"2012/12/10 00:00", 1
"2012/12/10 00:00", 2
"2012/12/10 00:00", 3
"2012/12/10 00:00", 4
"2012/12/10 00:00", 5
...
```

The result should basically be a list of how many instances of notepad where running at a certain hour in time.

```
table result(
   day_occured [datetime],
   hour_occured [tinyint],
   instances_running [int]
)
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: If you've got a `datetime` (which means we're all probably going to assume this is SQL Server, is this correct?), why do you have the `hour_occured` column?

Comment: can the dates in event span more than one day?

Comment: once you have event_Temp you can use `count(distinct machine_name) as instances_running / group by day, hour`, right?  I don't see why you need the calendar table.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Unfortunately this the expected input by the application and I am not able to modify the application itself and Yes it is SQL Server Transact SQL.

Comment: @Beth: Yes this can be the case. The result is turned into a graph by an application if there is no entry for a particular hour then the line of the graph appears broken. The calendar table is generated and maintained by the application.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As  Clockwork-Muse pointed out, my last answer had some flaws. Here is a different approach.

Without zero hours included...

```
DECLARE @MinDate datetime = (SELECT TOP 1 start_tstamp FROM [event] ORDER BY start_tstamp ASC)
DECLARE @MaxDate datetime = (SELECT TOP 1 stop_tstamp FROM [event] ORDER BY stop_tstamp DESC)

WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT @MinDate AS dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(hh, 1, dt)
      FROM Dates s
     WHERE DATEADD(hh, 1, dt) <= @MaxDate)

SELECT 
  CONVERT(date,d.dt,101) AS [day_occured],
  DATEPART(hh, d.dt) AS [hour_occured],
  COUNT(*) AS [instances_running]
FROM @Event e
JOIN Dates d ON e.start_tstamp <= d.dt
        AND e.stop_tstamp  > = d.dt 
GROUP BY d.dt
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

With zero hours included...

```
SET @MinDate = CONVERT(date,@MinDate,101)
SET @MaxDate = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(dd,1,@MaxDate))
SET @MaxDate = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -2,@MaxDate)

SELECT 
  CONVERT(date,d.dt,101) AS [day_occured],
  DATEPART(hh, d.dt) AS [hour_occured],
  SUM(CASE ISNULL(exe_name,'-1') WHEN '-1' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS [instances_running]
FROM [event] e
FULL JOIN Dates d ON e.start_tstamp <= d.dt
         AND e.stop_tstamp  >= d.dt 
GROUP BY d.dt
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Okay, the ordering of your comparisons was throwing me off.  Two things: 1) There is no such thing as hour '24', it's hour '0' (of the next day).  2) This doesn't work for any events that cross date boundaries (which, in a comment posted after your answer, is indicated to be possible).  Also, I'm not sure, but I think the OP may also want '0-count' rows...